# What is the difference in <svg> and <canvas> implementation in given code?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, canvas, html5-canvas

```html
<body>
<svg width="200" height="200">
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="70" stroke-width="10" stroke="red" fill="green" />
</svg>

<canvas id="canvas01" width="200" height="200">
</canvas>

<script>
  var c = document.getElementById("canvas01");
  var cx = c.getContext("2d");
  cx.beginPath();
  cx.arc(100,100,70,0,2*Math.PI);
  cx.lineWidth = 10;
  cx.strokeStyle = 'red';
  cx.stroke();
  cx.fillStyle = 'black';
  cx.fill();
</script>     
 
</body>
</html>
```

I am missing something here while comparing basics of `<svg>` and `<canvas>` 
Why is the border width of the circles in output different? Isn't the `stroke-width="10"` and `cx.lineWidth = 10` supposed to give the equal border width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `fill` after `stroke` -> overwrite half the stroke.

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="70" stroke-width="10" stroke="red" fill="green" />
</svg>

<canvas id="canvas01" width="200" height="200"></canvas>

<script>
  var c = document.getElementById("canvas01");
  var cx = c.getContext("2d");
  cx.beginPath();
  cx.arc(100,100,70,0,2*Math.PI);
  cx.lineWidth = 10;
  cx.strokeStyle = 'red';
  cx.fillStyle = 'black';
  cx.fill();
  cx.stroke();
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! :) Can you direct me to some documentation/ manuals where such small details are provided on `canvas`?

Comment: Sorry, i cannot. In general i would recommend the documentation found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/).

Comment: Yeah, I went through MDN. Couldn't find such details. Thanks for your quick help!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: You code does `stroke()` first, and the `fill()`. Surely that's the only documentation you need?  On the SVG side, an element with both and fill specified gets filled first (by default). That is documented [in the SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/single-page.html#render-PaintingShapesAndText).

Comment: @PaulLeBeau: I would say the important distinction is that drawing on a canvas is sequential and imperative for the most part while SVGs are declarative. So for the former order has to be kept in mind.